# How do I create multiple commands using command_prefix=‘!’?

Tags: python, discord

I am creating a Discord bot and am not experiencing any success creating custom commands with a command_prefix=‘!’.

E.g. I want to create, using the !-sign as the prefix, multiple commands that can even accept other arguments if you know exactly what you want within that command. Something like this:
!creeds
-or if you know what creed, you could use “!creeds Nicene” or “!creeds Athanasian” or if you want a list just use the base command “!creeds” and it will provide a list.

I have been told to use cogs and have not had any success with those, yet. Though I know I will need a database (using SQLite3) which I am also working on.

@jh316, all I have is this so far:

```
@client.event #basic event using a !command.
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author != client.user:
        if msg.content.lower().startswith("!hi"):
            await msg.channel.send(f"Hi, {msg.author.display_name}!")
```

Comment: Using the # symbol as your prefix is probably a bad idea, since Discord already starts autocompleting channel names when you type #.

Comment: Fair enough. Using ‘!’ instead.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code you can post? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? https://onecompiler.com/python/3yc5xaqce

```
def purify(string):
    return string.lower().strip()
    
def handleMessage(msg):
    prefix = "!"
    delimiter = ":"
    
    if msg[0:1] != "!":
        print("This is not a command")
        #exit
    
    splitMessage = msg[1:len(msg)].split(":")
    cmd = purify(splitMessage[0])
    param = "" if len(splitMessage) <= 1 else purify(splitMessage[1])
    
    response = executeCommand(cmd, param)
    
    #Now use the response
    print(response)
    
def executeCommand(command, parameter):
    #Actually use command here...
    response = "Sorry, we don't have that one!"
    if command == "creed":
        if parameter == "nicene":
            response = "We believe in one God, the Father almighty, maker of heaven and earth, of all things visible and invisible..."
        elif parameter == "apostles":
            response = "I believe in God, the Father almighty, creator of heaven and earth."

    return response

#Examples
handleMessage("!creed: Nicene")
handleMessage("!creed: Apostles")
handleMessage("!creed: Athanasian")
```

Obviously you would want to remove the examples and put a single `handleMessage` reference in your discord client event message handler. Does this help?

Anyway, I love the idea!

Comment: Kinda? I'm going to be using a number of commands that I want to pull from a database and print as a formatted message in Discord. So I was thinking along the lines of using "
!creeds list" would fetch the "list" from the database and print that. Or if I used "!creeds <parameter>" it would fetch that from the database and print it, too.

Comment: cogs are the best way to go @OrthoBotHistorian, they are very simple... instead of using a database you separate each command/group of similar commands into a file then load it/unload it at runtime, for non client/server interactions, sqlite3 would be the way to go though as i see you have figured out. Another little fix would be to define the prefix at startup of the bot instead of including it in every if statement to check if a command has been sent

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Client or a Bot? You should be importing `from discord.ext.commands import Bot`. The Bot class has a decorator to create commands:

```py
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

TOKEN = "your secret bot token from the Discord developer page"

bot = Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def settings(context):
    await context.reply("You executed command `settings`!")

@bot.command()
async def hello(context):
    await context.reply("You executed command `hello`!")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Now your users will be able to type `!settings` and `!hello` in Discord to trigger these commands.

Be careful though, because if you define your own `on_message` like you did in your code, these commands will not automatically be called. You have to invoke them yourself:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    context = await bot.get_context(message)
    await bot.invoke(context)
```

There is plenty of information online about how these commands work and how you can pass in arguments and cast them to the correct type automatically. [This tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-make-discord-bot-commands-in-python-2cae39cbfd55) is one of the first Google Search results when I search "discord.py commands", and it looks like a decent tutorial that you could read.

Comment: Yes, it is a bot. When I put in the "from discord.ext.commands import Bot" the "Bot" is a darker gray, is that just because it isn't defined? I'm looking at tutorials, too, so I'm trying to absorb all of this as I go. Thank you kindly again for your help.

Comment: Are you using PyCharm? If the Bot is dark gray, it means you have imported it but you aren't using it anywhere. Notice how in my code example I actually create a bot (the 4th line there, `bot = Bot(...)`